# Error while loading library "libicuuc.so.63" on termux

Tags: r, linux, termux

Since I have made an update of packages on Termux via:

```
pkg upgrade
```

R can't start, I receive this error message:

```
$R
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE 
 "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R": 
library "libicuuc.so.63" not found
Aborted
```

I tried to reinstall the package 'libicu' through:

```
$pkg install libicu
```

but it has not worked:

```
Reading state information... Done
libicu is already the newest version (64.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Does anyone have any tips or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used linux, It is uncertain. Have you tried this code?

```
$pkg update -f
```

Regarding reinstalling problem, Did you clear it before install the package?
IF you don't, try this code.

```
$pkg delete #add package name
```

Comment: The update of R has solved this problem.thanl you much!